# Trying to rebuild Visual Studio files but I get an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4, cl.exe

`ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception: No 32-bit compiler toolchain found in  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe`

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on my computer and I have installed every C++ add-on I could find in the modify menu. I cannot even start the project because it asks to rebuild it from source. I am currently working with a team and we are using git, if that helps. I have tried to google my way out of the problem but I only managed to find that you need to install the C++ components on Visual Studio 2015 (which I don't have and can't download).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this by myself. First, in the Visual Studio Installer I had to install Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240.0). After the install i once again ran the "Generate Visual Studio project files". It will generate "ProjectName.sln" file, but it will give the same error message. Finally you need to open the .sln file and rebuild solution. That did the trick for me.